# Arguments not needed when using foldl in haskell?

Tags: haskell, arguments, foldleft

What I don't get is how it is possible to use foldl in this way in haskell. I do not understand how the argument ( in this case list) is carried over implicitly:

```
addAll :: [Int] -> Int
addAll =  foldl (+) 0

-- This is how I could write foldl to simplify addAll where xs is clearly defined

addAll :: [Int] -> Int
addAll xs = foldl (+) 0 xs
```

or

```
addAll :: [Int] -> Int
addAll = \ xs -> foldl (+) 0 xs
```

But I don't really understand the first example. So basically I wonder how it is possible for something to be evaluated like that in haskell?

Comment: `foldl (+) 0` produces a function that maps a list to the sum.

Comment: Technically, because of currying, all the functions in Haskell take exactly _one_ argument. `foldl` takes one argument, which is `(+)` in your code. It happens that the result of `foldl (+)` is a function, so that can take something as its argument -- `0`, in your code. It also happens that the new result is also a function, so it can take `xs` as argument. Summing up, `foldl`, `foldl (+)`, `foldl (+) 0`, `foldl (+) 0 xs` are all valid expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don't really understand the first example. So basically I wonder how it is possible for something to be evaluated like that in haskell?

The `foldl (+) 0` produces a *function*. A function of type `(Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`, so why would you need an extra parameter? The `addAll` is a function as well.

In functional programming, functions are "first class citizens". This means that you can pass functions as parameters, and that the result can be a function. In Haskell every function takes *exactly* one parameter. Indeed:

```
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) ->  b ->  t a -> b
```

is short for:

```
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> (b -> (t a -> b))
```

`foldl` is thus a function that takes as parameter a function of type `(b -> a -> b)`, and produces a function of type `b -> t a -> b`. This thus means that `foldl (+)` has type:

```
foldl (+) :: (Foldable f, Num b) => b -> (f b -> b)
```

again  a function that in this case takes a parameter the base case for `foldl`, and returns then a function that maps a `(Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> f a`. If you write `foldl (+) 0`, this is thus short for `(fold (+)) 0`.

Comment: I just tried it out with max to check  what number is bigger, 10 or the other and it works, how cool is that.

Comment: ```Haskell-- max :: (Ord a) => a -> (a -> a)

max10 :: Int -> Int
max10 = max 10```

Comment: @DN: yes. All functions take one parameter, so you can make functions that calculate the maximum compared to 10 as you did :)

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it when I read about Curried functions just now. Thanks a lot, understanding curried functions was the key and especially that "Every function in Haskell officially only takes one parameter.".

Answer (score 4):

Remember that all functions in Haskell are curried. `foldl` is no exception; it has type `Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`, which means it takes an argument of type `(b -> a -> b)` and returns a function of type `Foldable t => b -> t a -> b`.

That function is *also* curried. `foldl (+)` takes an argument of type `Int b => b` and returns a function of type `(Foldable t, Num b) => t b -> b`.

Thus, `foldl (+) 0` has type `(Foldable t, Num b) => t b -> b`, and your type annotation makes the restrictions `t ~ []` and `b ~ Int`.